# How to parse web elements into notepad using Python?

Tags: python, windows, parsing, web, notepad

can anyone help me with "extracting" stuff from site using Python? Here is the info :
I have folder name with set of numbers (they are ID of item) and i have to use that ID for entering page and then "scrap" info from page to my notepad... It's like this : http://www.somesite.com/pic.mhtml?id=[ID]... I need to exctract picture link (picture link always have ID.jpg at the end of the file)from it and write it in notepad and then replace that txt name with name of the picture... Picture is always in title tags... Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a data scraper - http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/ will help you pull data off of websites. You can then load that data into a variable, write it to a file, or do anything you normally do with data.

Answer (score 0):

You could try parsing the html source for images.
Try something similar:

```
class Parser(object):
__rx = r'(url|src)="(http://www\.page\.com/path/?ID=\d*\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)'

def __crawl(self, url):
    images = []
    code = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    for line in code.split('\n'):
        imagesearch = re.search(self.__rx, line)
        if imagesearch:
            image = '%s.%s' % (imagesearch.group(2), imagesearch.group(4))
            images.append(image)
    return images
```

it's untestet, you may want to check the regex